Background only shows when searching for applications
Background only shows when searching for applications. I am new to using Ubuntu so I don't know how to fully explain my problem, but I made this video of it: Video


Does the problem persist if you set a new background picture ? Right-click on the desktop, select 'Change background' in the drop-down menu, and then select a background picture.
